# How to handle special characters

Tags: r, loops, input

I need some help with R programming.

Basically I need to get user input from the user and use it as a variable in my R script.

When getting the user input the following checks need to be made.

1. to see if missing values exist:

   - else Prompt user to reenter
2. Check to see that only alpha numeric characters are entered.

   - else prompt user to reenter.
3. allow some special characters: $,#,&, etc
4. White space is allowed as in first name, " ", last name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to do with the `else if` part of your code. The nature of `readline()` is that it will return a string of the user's input. Are there any specific characters you don't want included in the input? You could use `grepl()` to identify them and prevent the user from entering them as an input.

If you are trying to ensure that the user inputs something then you should use a `while` loop as suggested in the comments. If you are going to use your variable in R after the function runs then you need to `return()` the value of `v1` - the user input. If you are trying to replace the space in between the first and last name with %20 then you may want to use `gsub()`. See the code below.

```
fun1 <- function(){
  v1 <- c("")
  v1 <- readline(prompt='Enter your First & Last Name: ')
  while (v1==""){
    v1 <- readline("You forgot to enter your Name. Please try again: ")
  }
  return(gsub(" ", "%20", v1))
}

> "David%20Smith"
```

Comment: I attempted to modify Imad's code, but have a few additional questions.

Comment: I have edited my code in the question to reflect Imad's answer. Additional questions. (a) How do I get to use the return statement in my program. Not just show on the console. (b) The [:blank:] doesn't seem to work. Am I using it incorrectly. (c) Now the output doesn't show the %20 for the missing & special characters. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could direct the function `fun1()` to some variable in order to store it in that variable. Regarding the [:blank:], I'm not sure what you're trying to replace in your string. You can refer to `?regex` to see how to use regular expressions in R.